# Deactivate a rule flow group in drools

Tags: drools

I have a drl file which has rules inside 2 ruleflow-groups: "first-ruleflow-group" and "second-ruleflow-group" . The activation of these groups depend on "rule A" and "rule B". Is there any way in which I can deactivate rule B to fire when rule A condition matches, so that the focus is set only to "first-ruleflow-group"?

```
rule "rule A"
    when
        eval(true);
   then
        drools.setFocus("first-ruleflow-group");
end

rule "rule B"
    when
        eval(true);
   then
        drools.setFocus("second-ruleflow-group");
end
```

Comment: Nit: `eval(true)` is unnecessary. Just leave the when clause blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rules rely on exclusive conditions.

Simple example. Let's say we have an application dealing with calendar events. We have a rule flow for public holidays. We have a rule flow for religious holidays. There are some religious holidays which are also public holidays; for these we only want to fire the public holiday rules.

```
rule "Public Holidays"
when
  Holiday( isPublic == true )
then
  drools.setFocus("publicholiday-flow");
end

rule "Religious Holidays"
when
  Holiday( isReligious == true,
           isPublic == false )
then
  drools.setFocus("religiousholiday-flow");
end
```

So, basically, modify your "rule B" to include a condition that negates the rule A condition, so that if Rule A matches, Rule B necessarily does not.

---

A second solution would be to have a rule in your first rule flow (triggered by A) set a condition such that rule B doesn't trigger. It's basically similar to the previous solution except that the condition keeping Rule B from triggering is dynamic.

As an example, imagine an application that determines how much someone owes for parking. Parking rates are set by day -- there's one rate for Monday through Friday, a rate for Saturday, and Sundays are free. In addition, there are other discounts applied -- for example senior citizens, or if the total amount time parked is less than 5 minutes. The day-of-the-week rates are determined using the first rule flow (A), and the discounts are determined using the second rule flow (B). If it is Sunday, there's no reason to fire the second set of rules.

You could either write the discount rule flow trigger to explicitly not fire for Sundays, or you could have the Sunday rate rule retract or insert data such that it makes the discount rules no longer valid for running.

```
rule "Day Rates"
when
then
  drools.setFocus("dayrates-flow");
end

rule "Discounts"
when
  exists(Rate( hourly > 0 ))
then
  drools.setFocus("discounts-flow");
end

// The Sunday rule, part of the dayrates-flow, sets hourly = 0, which makes
// the "Discounts" rule no longer valid to fire.
rule "Sunday Rate"
ruleflow-group "dayrates-flow"
when
  not(Rate())
  Request( day == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) // when parking on Sunday...
then
  Rate rate = new Rate();
  rate.setHourlyRate(0.0);
  insert(rate);
end
```

---

Yet another option would be to trigger the second rule flow from within the first rule flow, but only as needed.

Reusing the previous example with parking:

```
rule "Day Rates"
when
then
  drools.setFocus("dayrates-flow");
end


// Here are some day rate rules. Most are omitted for brevity. We include three (3)
// to show regular rates, the special case of Sunday, and how we trigger the discount
// rate rules

rule "Saturday Rate"
ruleflow-group "dayrates-flow"
when
  not(Rate())
  Request( day == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY )
then
  Rate rate = new Rate();
  rate.setHourly(1.0); // Saturday rate: $1/hr
  insert(rate);
end

rule "Sunday Rate"
ruleflow-group "dayrates-flow"
when
  not(Rate())
  Request( day == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY )
then
  Rate rate = new Rate();
  rate.setHourlyRate(0.0); // Sunday rate: free
  insert(rate);
end

// This rule only triggers the next rule flow when the rate is positive (eg not Sunday)
rule "Transition to Discounts"
ruleflow-group "dayrates-flow"
when
  exists(Rate( hourly > 0 ))
then
  drools.setFocus("discount-flow");
end
```